# Will Google API Client Library for JavaScript be unavailable after March 31, 2023?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-signin, google-api-javascript-client

I am developing a Web Application based on Google App Engine.
This application uses [Google Sign-In JavaScript platform library for Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) for Oauth 2.0 and [Google API Client Library for JavaScript](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) to access Google APIs.

We recently received the following notice.
https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/03/gis-jsweb-authz-migration.html

> Complete your migration prior to March 31, 2023, after which the Platform Library will no longer be available for download and web apps relying upon deprecated authorization features to obtain access tokens for calling Google APIs will no longer work as intended.

> Web applications using gapi.client from the Google API Client Library implicitly load and use the Platform Library’s soon to be deprecated gapi.auth2 module when working with access tokens to call Google APIs. Updates to your web app to explicitly include the new Identity Services library, manage access token requests, and replace auth2 module references with newer equivalent methods are necessary.

In accordance with this notice, I have replaced [Google Sign-In JavaScript platform library for Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) with [Google Identity Services JavaScript library](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview).
But I plan to continue to use [Google API Client Library for JavaScript](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) for access to the Google API.

Will [Google API Client Library for JavaScript](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) be unavailable after March 31, 2023?

Comment: At any rate @T.Sasaki I have contacted the identity team to be sure, I will let you know if i hear anything back from them.  At the very least we can get a link to the p3 library source and some updates to the documentation for migration for you.

Comment: We can't say what Google will deprecate and when; they especially are known for killing their products unexpectedly. So we cannot possibly answer whether some library will be available in the future (even the near future). This makes the question "will <any> library be available/unavailable after <some date in the future>" opinion-based.

Answer (score 3):

There is a little confusion here - let me try to clean it up a bit.

[Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) is for sign-in and authorization.  It lets you

1. login, sign-in authenticate a user.
2. It also lets you authorize an application to access users' private data behind one of the google APIs (drive, calendar, ....)

There is a difference between sign-in and authorize.    The Google API client library for JavaScript is for authorization.

Google has released a new [web identity system](https://developers.google.com/identity). This system splits the two up.  Identity / signin / authencation now falls under the [authencation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) section of the documentation, and for JavaScript you get a bunch of shiny buttons you can click to login a user into your application.

While authorization is under a different system, called [3p authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/load-3p-authorization-library).

To answer your question: no, [Google API Javascript client libary](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) is not being deprecated. If it was, it would say so on the Github page.  You can continue to use this.  Or switch to 3p - it is still unclear to me if this is the same library or a new library.  I have sent a message off to Google to find out.

Comment: related to this question, do you have any idea if the legacy Google Sign-In JavaScript library will stop functioning after March 31, 2023? The docs seem to be updated to say that it should still work for existing client IDs.

Comment: Yes the legacy google sign-in library will stop working March 31, 2023 they are going to start shutting down endpoint on that date it may take a while for it to roll out to everyone.   You need not change your client id to switch to the new Google sign-in nothing about that will change.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure? I ask because the docs seem to indicate otherwise: "By default, new client IDs are now blocked from using the older platform library; existing client IDs are unaffected." https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference

There's also the deprecation page which states that the legacy library will be deprecated but will continue to work until it is sunset (at a future yet-to-be determined date): https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/deprecation-and-sunset

Comment: not sure I understand your question client ids are not limited to a specific library.

Comment: Ah, I was asking if you're sure the legacy google sign-in library will stop working March 31, 2023. It looks like it will continue to work until it's sunset at a later date. "For existing OAuth client ID(s) using the deprecated library, you can still use the deprecated library until they're sunset, but any new OAuth client ID cannot use the deprecated library." https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/deprecation-and-sunset. That seems to indicate the legacy library should continue to work, no?

Comment: Okay I see your point as far as I know March 31, 2023 is the sunset date (give or take a few weeks they roll it out over about a month.) but it seems that page is not showing that I will contact the team and see whats up.  Message sent I will let you know when I hear more.

Comment: That'd be hugely helpful. We've tried finding out for ourselves but the only email address provided is for feedback only (gis-migration-feedback@google.com). Looking forward to hearing back from you!

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo we are also super confused about this! The conflicting information from Google is very frustrating. It seems like it will continue to work until the TBD sunset date, but would really like a confirmation of that.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo have you heard back from the team by chance?